# why telerik RadTimeLine dont show some properties

Tags: wpf, silverlight, reference, telerik, rad-controls

First, i have some difficulties to find, reference and use the control, i try referencing a lot of Telerik.Windows.Something and when i typed telerik:RadTimeLine the VS intellisense doesnt show anything.
I ended up referencing ALL telerik dll, for now, the markup show me the RadTimeLine, but some properties are not found when i compile the projetc

Here is the test project [(MyTestProject)](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bzamt5nikt3KVzRxV3V4X0ctbnc)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact the RadTimeLine was included only in the 2012 version. Sorry for not serach for this information before